# Contact Form 7 returning status "validation_failed" when submitting form in nuxtjs

Tags: wordpress, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js, contact-form-7

So I built a nuxtjs app with the wordpress api and I'm trying to integrate a form with Contact Form 7 in it. I followed several tutorials and I think there is only one tiny problem to master. So this is how my formdata and post request looks like.

```
formSubmit(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            const formData = new FormData();
            const dat = {
                'your-radio': this.formRadio,
                'your-project': this.formProject,
                'your-name': this.formName,
                'your-tel': this.formTel,
                'your-email': this.formMail,
                'your-date': this.formDate
            }
            for(const name in dat) {
                formData.append(name, dat[name])
            }

            for(var pair of formData.entries()){
                console.log(pair[0] + "," + pair[1])
            }

           this.$axios.post('https://example.wp/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/ID/feedback', {
               data: formData,
               headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
           })
           .then((response) => {
                console.log(response.data.message)
            })
```

This is the answer to the request:

[image]

On Postman the post request works fine, but when I remove the content type header I also get the same answer as in the screenshot. So maybe it has something to do with the content type header.

## EDIT

This might not be the solution for the error but I switched to XMLHttpRequest and now it seems to work.

Comment: What you are sending with Postman ans axios is the exact same content? What is the German error saying btw?

Comment: @kissu In Postman I'm sending exact the same body (form-data) with the same keys like in axios and the header is generated automatic. The error basically means that the 3 fields are mandatory even though there is content in the field.